# Edit BLE shield Framework for iOS 7

Tags: frameworks, ios7, arduino, deprecated

I'm using the BLE_Framework from RedBearLab for my iOS-BLE-Arduino project. I designed an App for iOS 7 but the Xcode showed the 'isConnected' in the TableViewController.h is deprecated. I'm not a programmer so I need some help on editing the code to keep its function. Thank you.
Following is the code.

```
(IBAction)btnScanForPeripherals:(id)sender
```

{
    if (ble.activePeripheral)
        if(ble.activePeripheral.***isConnected***)    ***//!'isConnect' is deprecated. first deprecated in iOS 7.0***
        {
            [[ble CM] cancelPeripheralConnection:[ble activePeripheral]];
            [btnConnect setTitle:@"Connect" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            return;
        }

```
if (ble.peripherals)
    ble.peripherals = nil;

[btnConnect setEnabled:false];
[ble findBLEPeripherals:2];

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(float)2.0 target:self selector:@selector(connectionTimer:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

[indConnecting startAnimating];
```

}

Another problem is that the UUID is deprecated in iOS 7.0 too.

```
if (!service)
{
    printf("Could not find service with UUID %s on peripheral with UUID %s\r\n",[self CBUUIDToString:serviceUUID],[self UUIDToString:p.UUID]);
    return;
}
```

Any thing I can do to fix it?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little late but I found an answer for .isconnected. However I'm still working on the UUID

```
if(ble.activePeripheral.state == CBPeripheralStateConnected)
```